# CSS - Maintain image ratio whose height is 100% when its width would force it to deform?

Tags: html, css, image

I've got an image whose height is set as 100%. This makes the image display correctly as I would expect so long as there's plenty of width. However, when the screen's width is reduced eventually the image loses it's ratio because the width is squished while the height still remains 100%. I would like to have the image always stretch to the maximum size possible within the container without losing it's ratio. In other words, it the width is the limiting factor, the image should use 100% width and maintain ratio, but if the height is the limiting factor, than the image should use 100% height while maintaining its ratio, and it should be able to switch between these. Is there a way to do this purely in CSS? Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about a full-screen image?  Can we see some HTML?

Comment: `height:auto` will maintain aspect ratio...but do you want to stretch by height or width....both can't be done using css!!

Comment: @NoobEditor: So there's no way make set it so that the css will just determine whether the height or the width is the limiting factor and stretch it on that? You're saying I'd have to use JS for that?

Answer (score 1):

This should keep the correct ratio (providing you don’t *need* the height to be set to 100% for some reason).

```
img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

--EDIT--

If you want to retain a consistent height of the parent element then you can either:

- Hide the overflowing image using `overflow: hidden;`. Although this
  means you will lose some of the image at larger sizes. [See
  example.](http://jsfiddle.net/g7y5J/2/)
- Use `max-width` and `max-height` to stop the image growing at a
  certain point. This means you will potentially be left with some
  white space in the design. [See example.](http://jsfiddle.net/g7y5J/1/)

Comment: With this though, if the container's height is less then the image's height would be, the image just extends out of the container. Is their a way to insure that the height will also limit the size of the image and still keep the ratio?

Comment: There are a couple of approaches you could take to potentially solve your problem:

1. You could define the height of the image container div and set it to `overflow: hidden;`. Doing this would hide any overflow of when the image at large sizes — obviously you will lose some of the image. [Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/g7y5J/2/)

2. You could use `max-width` and `max-height` on the image to stop it enlarging when it gets to the maximum required size— although this could potentially leave some white space on your page. [Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/g7y5J/1/). If any of these help Ill update